# How to authenticate with Rails and Devise via API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I use gem Devise for user registration and auth. Everything goes well when I use web interface. But I want to auth via api. So, I made a request and got an error

```
#request
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X POST http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in -d '{"user" : { "email" : "admin@mail.ru", "password" : "r465ee"}}'

#error
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for ::1 at 2017-01-11 17:43:57 +0300
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"email"=>"admin@mail.ru", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "session"=>{"user"=>{"email"=>"admin@mail.ru", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)



ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):
```

Then I changed **application_controller.rb** but it didn't help.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, if: ->{request.format.json?}
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, if: Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }
```

Comment: Processing by DeviseTokenAuth::SessionsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"email"=>"admin@mail.ru", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "session"=>{"user"=>{"email"=>"admin@mail.ru", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
Unpermitted parameters: user, session

Comment: Then it could be completely different issue. Try to check your strong parameters and set up user and session parameters as permitted.

Comment: Finally I changed the request by removing 'user' (curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/sign_in -d '{ "email" : "admin@mail.ru", "password" : "r465eer465ee"}' )

Comment: Glad to know that your issue is resolved now. But as I mentioned in my last comment before you may have another issue with strong parameters (user and session). Check it out.